# Performance Testing In JMETER

Tags: performance, jmeter

While doing performance testing using **Jmeter** for a script, the viewstate captured while recording the script and the Runtime viewstate (i.e obtained after running the script in Jmeter) for a particular transaction does not match. Hence, could anyone suggest any solution to resolve this issue and capture the viewstate?

Answer (score 1):

Viewstate changes so you need to use the regular expression extractor to get this value from the previous page and pass to current. You can find some information on how to do this here:

http://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/JMeterTesting/ASPNETViewState

Another thread from the SQA forum:

http://www.sqaforums.com/showflat.php?Number=608116

Answer (score -1):

Once upon a time I worked on JMeter. I really don't remember if I faced the issue. But, I have captured my learning [here](http://deathbycode.blogspot.in/2010/11/load-testing-of-gui-using-jmeter.html). You can probably take a look. Would be happy if it helps you.